# React Native button does not work on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, react-native

I am using react-native-deck-swiper and have cards with buttons on them. The buttons do not work on iPhone 7 only. Tried several phones. What's even more interesting is that react-native-tinder-swipe-cards has the same issues, so it seems to be something that I'm doing wrong. Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Alert, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import Swiper from "react-native-deck-swiper";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Swiper
                  ref='swiper'
                  cards={['asdf','23423']}
                  renderCard={(question) => {
                      return (
                          <TouchableHighlight
                              onPress={() => Alert.alert('I work')}>
                            <Text> {question} </Text>

                          </TouchableHighlight>
                      )
                  }}
                  cardIndex={0}
              >
              </Swiper>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Same code without swiper works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Alert, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import Swiper from "react-native-deck-swiper";



export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => Alert.alert('asdf')}>
                    <Text> I like pants  </Text>

                </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

I highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: did you try a normal button? (not touchable highlight)

Comment: Yes I have, no go :(